# alternative to innerRef when using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am converting class based components to react hooks. I got confused on using the ref parts. Because, the way I am using it complains me that `The "innerRef" API has been removed in styled-components v4 in favor of React 16 ref forwarding, use "ref" instead like a typical component.`.

How do i make it work when using hooks?

```
const Tabs = ({activeTab, children}) => {
  const [tabsElements, setTabsElements] = useState([])

  return (
    <TabsContext.TabProvider activeTab={activeTab}>
      <TabsContext.TabConsumer>
        {value => (
          <ReactTabs>
            <TabsContainer>
              <ListTabs>
                {value.context.tabs.map(tab => (
                  <TabTitleItem
                    key={tab.id}
                    onClick={value.context.onClick(tab)}
                    id={tab.id}
                    innerRef={tabElement => {
                      if (!tabsElements[tab.id]) {
                        setTabsElements(tabElements => ({
                          ...tabElements,
                          [tab.id]: tabElement,
                        }))
                      }
                    }}
                    isActiveTab={value.context.activeTab.id === tab.id}
                  >
                    <TabAnchorItem>{tab.title}</TabAnchorItem>
                  </TabTitleItem>
                ))}
              </ListTabs>

              <ActiveTabBorder
                activeTabElement={tabsElements[value.context.activeTab.id]}
              />
            </TabsContainer>

            {children}
          </ReactTabs>
        )}
      </TabsContext.TabConsumer>
    </TabsContext.TabProvider>
  )
}
```

Here is the demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/z3moq8662p

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot update state within the ref callback method. Secondly you simply need to pass `ref` instead of `innerRef` to the `TabTitleItem` component since it internally handles ref using `forwardRef`

```
const Tabs = ({ activeTab, children }) => {
  const [tabsElements, setTabsElements] = useState([]);
  const tabElements = useRef({});

  return (
    <TabsContext.TabProvider activeTab={activeTab}>
      <TabsContext.TabConsumer>
        {value => (
          <ReactTabs>
            <TabsContainer>
              <ListTabs>
                {console.log("value", value.context)}
                {value.context.tabs.map(tab => (
                  <TabTitleItem
                    key={tab.id}
                    onClick={value.context.onClick(tab)}
                    id={tab.id}
                    ref={tabElement => {
                      tabElements.current[tab.id] = tabElement;
                    }}
                    isActiveTab={value.context.activeTab.id === tab.id}
                  >
                    <TabAnchorItem>{tab.title}</TabAnchorItem>
                  </TabTitleItem>
                ))}
              </ListTabs>
              <ActiveTabBorder
                activeTabElement={tabsElements[value.context.activeTab.id]}
              />
            </TabsContainer>

            {children}
          </ReactTabs>
        )}
      </TabsContext.TabConsumer>
    </TabsContext.TabProvider>
  );
};
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mynmjyovjj)**

Comment: its not showing border line because ActiveTabBorder could not pass the selected active tab elements. Its relying on tabsElements state. It was working when i used class based but not here

Comment: it shows but not initially only after clicking the tabs. The background color has to be changed though.

Comment: Can you see by changing the background-color of ActiveTabBorder that it does not show up initially

Comment: @milan Sorry for the delay, I saw your other post on SO and posted the answer to it for your above query